# Discrete Mathematics Symmetric Diffirence Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I've been trying to find a proof for the following problem but have been unable to come up with anything myself:

Say we have A, B, C part of a universe U
show that if $$A \Delta C = B \Delta C \rightarrow A = B$$

I've been able to use set operations to change the form of the problem into a logics one:

$${x | X \in A \cup C \vee x \notin A \cap C}  $$
$${x | x \in A \vee x \in C \vee x \notin (x \in A \wedge x \in C)}$$

A second thought was using the definition of symmetric diffirence
where $$A \Delta C = (A \cup C) - (A \cap C)$$

Can anyone provide a step by step proof or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Suppose the symmetric differences are equal but you have a point $x\in A\setminus B$. There are two cases to check: $x\in C$ and $x\notin C$. In either case you find that $x$ belongs to only one of the symmetric differences.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it only belonging to one of the symmetric diffirences, if A symmetric diffirence C != B symmetric diffirence C then the entire problem wouldn't hold right?

Comment: That is the entire point. What I proposed was an outline for an indirect proof.

Comment: My bad I understand your intention now, I will look at that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the nicest way is to first prove

- $A\triangle (B\triangle C) = (A\triangle B)\triangle C$
- $A\triangle A = \varnothing$
- $A\triangle\varnothing = A$

Then applying $\triangle C$ to both sides of your hypothesis quickly yields the conclusion.

(That is, start with
$ A\triangle C = B\triangle C
\implies (A\triangle C)\triangle C = (B\triangle C)\triangle C $.)

Comment: You mean apply $$ \Delta C $$ to the last part? Could you be so kind as to maybe write it out further?

Comment: Added a bit....

Comment: Thanks just before you updated the answer I believe I found A reasonable proof, might need slight adjustments though but this greatly helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is close to a proof by contradiction but don't feel it is formal enough yet looking for help on fixing it:

- symmetric diffirence is the set of elements which are in either of the sets and not in their intersection.
- the intersection of two sets is the set that contains all elements that are present in both sets.
- so say I have an $$ x \in ( A \Delta C ) $$ and $$x \in ( A \Delta C )$$ then A = B because there can not be two symmetric differences of C that are the same unless A = B

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer inspired by Steven Taschuk:

Given that:

- $A\Delta (B\Delta C) = (A\Delta B)\Delta C$
- $ A\Delta C = B\Delta C$
- $ A \Delta \emptyset = A$
- $ A \Delta A = \emptyset$

The proof follows:

$$ A \Delta \emptyset = A$$
$$ \leftrightarrow$$
$$ A \Delta (C\Delta C) $$
$$ \leftrightarrow$$
$$ (A \Delta C) \Delta C $$
$$ \leftrightarrow$$
$$ (B \Delta C) \Delta C $$
$$ \leftrightarrow$$
$$ B \Delta (C\Delta C) $$
$$ \leftrightarrow$$
$$ B \Delta \emptyset $$
$$ \leftrightarrow$$
$$ B $$

Feedback on correctness is greatly appreciated.